# Django's Admin Interface for Read-Only Model?

Tags: python, database, django, model, readonly

I have a Django model whose fields are read-only, populated from a database.

I have found that the **admin interface** is a great way to visualize my data, but whenever I try using it, I run into a problem: It seems to require *write* access to the database, which I don't have.
(i.e. it tries to create tables called `auth_user`, `django_session`, etc. in the read-only database... I managed to disable the latter but can't disable the former.)

How do I use the admin interface with read-only access?

#### Or, if this is not possible:

How do I make a temporary database (hopefully in memory, or on disk if necessary) to make it happy?

Comment: Django has an admin log to track changes users make through the admin.  There's no option to disable it, either, sadly.  You might need a micro-database, just sqlite, to make it happy.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this:

- Create an in-memory [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) database (use `:memory:` as the database) for the internal data
- Use a database router for redirecting the reads to the other database